# How can I do groubwise multiplication with two grouby terms?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am having a DataFrame with a bunch of companies, each company is assigned to one of five groups (ESG Bottom, ESG 4, ESG 3, ESG 2 or ESG Top).
[image]

Now I need to compute the weight of each company within its group in order to then compute their weighted group return and hence the overall group return.

I have managed to use groupby to get each groups summed market capital (MC)
[image]
and each companies individual MC.
[image]

**My question** is, how can I now divide the companies' individual MC by its respective total group MC and save the resulting weight in the "Weight in Quintile PF" column?

I could somehow manage to do this with a clumsy and slow for-loop but there must be a more elegant one (or two) liner which divides the inividual company MC with the respective total group MC.

Comment: kindly provide a sample dataframe, with expected output. The answer to that should guide you in your actual data

Comment: Is there a best practice on how to upload the data for download or just provide some pd.DataFrame(data) example?

Comment: [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) should guide you

Comment: I made a sample of 10 rows for replication but failing to make `.to_dict()` print out the whole sample df. Although I now spent about 20 minutes searching for a fix I could not find one. `df_sample.to_dict()` only returns one row which is rather useless for replicatioon. Is there a way to circumvent this restriction? I tried `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None),
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` but those did not heal the issue that only one row of the df_sample is displayed.

Comment: trim your dataframe to just the columns needed, or a small chunk (say quintile PF, MC). then something like `df.loc[10].to_dict()` should be fine

Comment: @sammywemmy Would this be enough?
Furthermore what is the reason for this restriction in `.to_dict()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way using a clumsy for loop using mask:

```
    for label in labels:
       mask = df_single_MC['Quintile PF']==label
       df_single_MC['Weight in Quintile PF'][mask] = df_single_MC['MC'][mask].values / quintile_MCs[label]
```

It is not pretty but it solves my problem, the second part of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126485/13678585) helped me.

I still would be curious if there is a neater solution **without a for loop** using e.g. apply and or lambda since I still have not fully figured them out.